# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepos'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring-boot

There is a User Bean as the model. The controller class is UserController and UserRepository is the repository class.

This is the model class

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is the Controller class:

```
package com.prashant.flightreservation.controllers;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepos;

    @RequestMapping("/showReg")
    public String showRegistrationPage() {
        return "registerUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "registerUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        userRepos.save(user);
        return "login";

    }

}
```

Repository
Do I need to implement this interface?

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepos'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stack Overflow.

Please annotate UserRepository class by @Repository annotation.

Please look here: [UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name)