# No qualifying bean found for dependency [CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got the following errors, while running the project

```
Dec 09, 2019 9:42:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Dec 09, 2019 9:42:26 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Dec 09, 2019 9:42:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2019-12-09 09:42:26.497 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started 
2019-12-09 09:42:26.955 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Dec 09 09:42:26 IST 2019]; root of context hierarchy 
2019-12-09 09:42:27.175 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml] 
2019-12-09 09:42:31.202 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commonUtlityController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'countryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)} 
2019-12-09 09:42:31.216 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commonUtlityController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'countryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:518)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Dec 09, 2019 9:42:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'commonUtlityController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'countryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryServiceImpl': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1128)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:518)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:318)
    ... 35 more
```

This is my countryRepository.java file

I am not getting the error what exactly happen pls suggest me on below code what exactly i need to do.

This is my CountryService.java

countryServiceImpl.java

In commonUtlityController.java i also autowired countryService

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name/54773593#54773593

Answer (score 2):

The Error says - `No qualifying bean found for dependency [in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao.CountryRepository]`
You are trying to inject a class that is not annotted for dependency injection. You have to mark you `interface CountryRepository`with below annotation in order to Autowire it.

```
@Repository
interface CountryRepository {
//...
}
```

For reference - http://zetcode.com/springboot/annotations/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing annotation in repository.

```
package in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao;
import java.util.List;
import in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dto.PagingInfo;
import in.techchefs.anyspace.common.model.Country;

@Repository
public interface CountryRepository {
    Country getByIsoCode(String isoCode);
    Country getByCountryCode(String countryCode);
    List<Country> getCountryAndCurrencyList(String countryName,Integer pageNum,Integer maxNbPerPage);
    List<Country> getCountryAndCurrencyList(String countryName,PagingInfo pagingInfo);
    List<Country> getAllCountryList();
}
```

You can also extends your repository with other repositories like CrudRepository which have some methods to save some boilerplate code.
For more information about various repositories, you can refer this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-repositories

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add **@Repository**.
Spring @Repository annotation is a specialization of **@Component** annotation, so Spring Repository classes are **autodetected** by spring framework through classpath scanning.

```
package in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dao;
import java.util.List;
import in.techchefs.anyspace.common.dto.PagingInfo;
import in.techchefs.anyspace.common.model.Country;
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository {
Country getByIsoCode(String isoCode);
Country getByCountryCode(String countryCode);
List<Country> getCountryAndCurrencyList(String countryName,Integer 
pageNum,Integer 
maxNbPerPage);
List<Country> getCountryAndCurrencyList(String countryName,PagingInfo 
pagingInfo);
List<Country> getAllCountryList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The countryRepository should be annotated with @Repository tag. With your current configuration Spring will not scan the class and have knowledge about it. At the moment of booting and wiring will not find the countryRepositoryclass.

EDIT If adding the @Repository tag doesn't help, then I think that the problem might be now with the countryServiceImpl and countryService.

Try to annotate the countryService(interface) with @Service. As you should only have a single implementation for your service, you don't need to specify a name with the optional parameter @Service("countryService"). Spring will autogenerate it based on the interface' name.

The @Qualifier is not needed in the controller as you only have a single implementation for the service.