# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sendController'

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-mvc, azureservicebus

I have followed this tutorial to send message to an azure service queue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus

to my existing spring boot app but I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sendController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

User Class:

```
    package com.proyecto.demo.domain;

import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.mapping.Document;
import com.microsoft.azure.spring.data.cosmosdb.core.mapping.PartitionKey;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Document(collection = "tUser")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -295422703255886286L;

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;

    @PartitionKey
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    public User(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String address) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public User(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %s, %s", firstName, lastName, address);
    }
}
```

Controller Class:

```
    package com.proyecto.demo.web;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.proyecto.demo.domain.User;

@RestController
public class SendController {

    private static final String DESTINATION_NAME = "testqueue";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostMapping("/messages")
    public String postMessage(@RequestParam String message) {

        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(DESTINATION_NAME, new User(message));
        return message;
    }

}
```

pom xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
     instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
      4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.proyecto</groupId>
    <artifactId>FileUploaderProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FileUploaderProject</name>
    <description>FileUploader</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.4</azure.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

adding the application properties it used it like a yml I removed all the sensitive information

```
 azure:
  cosmosdb:
    database: testdb
    key: 
    uri: https://testcosmosql.documents.azure.com:443/
spring:
  jms:
    servicebus:
      connection-string:
      idle-timeout: 1800000
```

Here is some of the stack trace:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sendController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.proyecto.demo.FileUploaderProjectApplication.main(FileUploaderProjectApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/microsoft/azure/spring/autoconfigure/jms/ServiceBusJMSAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'jmsConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I tried different solution like disable: ActiveMQAutoConfiguration and some others that i found but none of them.

I tried a lot of the solution I found on stack, that this is related with the fact that jms is not instantiated. I added JMS to my pom file.

I also tried updating the version, I have tried a lot of different solutions but it is still not working

I tried this one as well:

[UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name)

Thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: can you share also your .properties file? maybe problem lying inside your servicebus configuration?

Comment: Hello Artur, I updated the post with the requested information. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello Artur, there was something wrong with my conn string thanks a lot for your help!

I had:

 connection-string: '"connstirng'

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that Spring isn't able to instantiate the `@Autowired` classes you've specified.

```
Error creating bean with name 'jmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource
```

Means, `JmsConnectionFactory` bean is not instantiated. I didn't find
JMS library in your pom.xml.

You can include the JMS library by adding the following to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then spring can instantiate `JmsConnectionFactory` bean.

Comment: Hello Abinash, It did not work can I shared any other information with you?

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your help Arthur was right there was something wrong with the connection string I had an connection-string: '"connstirng'