# Deployment failed on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat

I have Spring Boot, Maven project that runs perfectly from IDE, so I just made maven install, then placed .war file into Tomcat /webapps. And here's logs, I don't quite understand what is the problem with deployment

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-19 13:50:31.320 ERROR 19344 --- [bio-8080-exec-7] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'profileController' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/XAMPP/tomcat/webapps/DiplomaApplication/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/ProfileController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:893) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:173) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:153) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:95) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5669) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1320) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:683) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:209) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) [servlet-api.jar:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:603) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445) [catalina.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.92]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositoryRestConfiguration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1304) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1224) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'repositoryRestConfiguration' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:362) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:334) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732.repositories(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:276) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732.CGLIB$repositoryRestConfiguration$4(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa4734fa.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732.repositoryRestConfiguration(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 92 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userProjectionRepository' defined in com.diploma.application.repository.UserProjectionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1444) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1115) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.cacheRepositoryFactory(Repositories.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.populateRepositoryFactoryInformation(Repositories.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories.<init>(Repositories.java:85) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.repositories(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.java:208) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732.CGLIB$repositories$0(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa4734fa.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b183d732.repositories(<generated>) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.3.1.RELEASE.jar:3.3.1.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        ... 93 common frames omitted
```

It seems something wrong with repository beans, but I don't get what is acutual problem, program works fine good when launched from IDE. I even tried to create .jar file, then run it manualy in my Linux server from terminal, and it worked as planned (IDE probably makes same thing, it just calls java -jar *.jar, but I did it to be sure that I have this problem only when I deploy .war to Tomcat)

Comment: can you show the code and see whether it helps or not -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511/unsatisfieddependencyexception-error-creating-bean-with-name/54773593

Comment: I have many classes, so here is link to github repo: https://github.com/MiroshnykovDaniil/dipoma_application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you haven't given `@Repository` at the start of this class
Try running after adding this line

File path= `dipoma_application/src/main/java/com/diploma/application/repository/UserRepository.java /`

```
package com.diploma.application.repository;

import com.diploma.application.model.User;
import com.diploma.application.projection.user.UserOnlyInfoProjection;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

@Repository //<---added line
public interface UserProjectionRepository extends JpaRepository<User,String> {

    UserOnlyInfoProjection getDistinctTopById(String id);
}
```

EDIT :

The best way to trace the line of code / file which is causing trouble is to find the 1st line in the error logs which has the file directory of your code/project

It reduces ample amount of time :)

Comment: After your comment, I checked that question about @Repository, and then checked this class. I was quite amazed , how I missed this annotation, and program even worked without it. Anyway, thank you for solution.