# Spring Boot UnsatisfiedDependencyException for JpaRepository "Not a managed type" Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring Boot application with JPA, and I am encountering an UnsatisfiedDependencyException when running my application. The exception indicates that there is a problem with the ApartmentRepository bean:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apartmentController'... Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0... Not a managed type: class com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model.Apartment
```

Here are the relevant references to my code:

Apartment Entity:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Map;

@Entity
public class Apartment {
    // fields, constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Apartment Repository:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.repository_interfaces;

import com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.model.Apartment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ApartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Apartment, Long> {
    // query methods
}
```

Apartment Service:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.service;

import com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.repository_interfaces.ApartmentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ApartmentService {
    // constructor and methods
}
```

Apartment Controller:

```
package com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.controller;

import com.alphaomegazed.aoz_apartments.service.ApartmentService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class ApartmentController {
    // constructor and endpoints
}
```

The application fails to start, and I receive the error message above. My Apartment class is annotated with @Entity, and the repository interface extends JpaRepository. The Apartment class is in the same package as the repository interface.

I've checked for common issues such as ensuring the entity is in a package scanned by Spring, but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any idea why Spring Data JPA does not recognize my Apartment entity and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think this below link could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511

Comment: I think this below link could help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511511

Comment: Thank you @Shohreh.Safi, it appears that one of my main issues was the use of javax.persistence instead of jakarta, the other issue was with some other imports that I did not mention here.